# how shell pipe handles infinite loop

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell, pipe

Whenever I need to limit shell command output, I use less to paginate the results:

`cat file_with_long_content | less`

which works fine and dandy, but what I'm curious about is, less still works even if the output is never ending, consider having the following script in `inf.sh` file:

`while true; do date; done`

then I run

`sh inf.sh | less`

And it's still able to again paginate the results, so is it correct to say that pipe streams the result rather than waiting for the command to finish before outputting the result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, when you run `sh inf.sh | less` the two commands are run in parallel.  Data written into the pipe by the first process is buffered (by the kernel) until it is read by the second.  If the buffer is full (i.e., if the first command writes to the pipe faster than the second can read) then the next write operation will block until further space is available.  A similar condition occurs when reading from an empty pipe: if the pipe buffer is empty but the input end is still open, a read will block for more data.

See the [pipe(7)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/pipe.7.html) manual for details.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct. **Pipes are streams**.

You can code your own version of the `less` tool in very few lines of C code. Take the time to do it, including a short research on files and pipes, and you'll emerge with the understanding to answer your own question and more :).